# Python, Pandas: Merging several dataframes results in duplication of rows with uneven NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 dfs, which look like below

df1

```
                     _id        bs        ds        as        pf
0    2017-05-01 00:00:00  0.982218  0.906662  0.614119  0.999471
1    2017-05-01 00:05:00  0.983751  0.913266  0.585237  0.999571
2    2017-05-01 00:10:00  0.983012  0.914875  0.592698  0.999631
3    2017-05-01 00:15:00  0.981884  0.910922  0.589013  0.999536
4    2017-05-01 00:20:00  0.982611  0.913082  0.601056  0.999556
5    2017-05-01 00:25:00  0.982386  0.912358  0.598856  0.999650
```

df2

```
                    _id  avg_time_serve  
0   2017-05-01 00:00:00        0.520681            
1   2017-05-01 00:05:00        0.521580            
2   2017-05-01 00:10:00        0.517993            
3   2017-05-01 00:15:00        0.520662            
4   2017-05-01 00:20:00        0.514146            
5   2017-05-01 00:25:00        0.513723
```

df3

```
                    _id   total_distinct_ips    
0   2017-05-01 00:00:00             291094.0     
1   2017-05-01 00:05:00             287922.0     
2   2017-05-01 00:10:00             292103.0     
3   2017-05-01 00:15:00             295675.0     
4   2017-05-01 00:20:00             297813.0     
5   2017-05-01 00:25:00             302406.0
```

df4

```
                    _id  total_40x  total_50x
0   2017-05-01 00:00:00     162034          0
1   2017-05-01 00:05:00     162497          0
2   2017-05-01 00:10:00     161079          0
3   2017-05-01 00:15:00     163338          0
4   2017-05-01 00:20:00     167901          0
5   2017-05-01 00:25:00     164394          0
```

I'm trying to combine them by '_id' column. The '_id' column is in timestamp format.

I tried using the below approaches:

```
**Approach 1**

from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
final_df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left, right, on='_id', 
           how='outer'), dfs)

**Approach 2**
final_df = pd.Dataframe()

for df in dfs:
    if final_df.empty:
        final_df = df
    else:
        final_df = pd.merge(final_df, df, how='outer', on='_id')
```

Both approaches give below result:

```
                    _id        bs        ds        as        pf  \
0   2017-05-01 00:00:00  0.982218  0.906662  0.614119  0.999471
1   2017-05-01 00:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2   2017-05-01 00:05:00  0.983751  0.913266  0.585237  0.999571
3   2017-05-01 00:05:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4   2017-05-01 00:10:00  0.983012  0.914875  0.592698  0.999631
5   2017-05-01 00:10:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN

     avg_time_serve  total_distinct_ips  total_40x  total_50x
0               NaN            291094.0     162034          0
1          0.520681            291094.0     162034          0
2               NaN            287922.0     162497          0
3          0.521580            287922.0     162497          0
4               NaN            292103.0     161079          0
5          0.517993            292103.0     161079          0
```

**Approach 3**

I took out 'df1' from dfs list, and added a 'join'.

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df2, df3, df4]
final_df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left, right, on='_id', 
           how='outer'), dfs)
final_df = final_df.join(df1.set_index('_id'), on='_id')
```

and finally got the right result

```
                    _id  avg_time_serve  total_distinct_ips  total_40x 
0   2017-05-01 00:00:00        0.520681            291094.0     162034
1   2017-05-01 00:05:00        0.521580            287922.0     162497
2   2017-05-01 00:10:00        0.517993            292103.0     161079
3   2017-05-01 00:15:00        0.520662            295675.0     163338
4   2017-05-01 00:20:00        0.514146            297813.0     167901
5   2017-05-01 00:25:00        0.513723            302406.0     164394

     total_50x        bs        ds        as        pf
0            0  0.982218  0.906662  0.614119  0.999471
1            0  0.983751  0.913266  0.585237  0.999571
2            0  0.983012  0.914875  0.592698  0.999631
3            0  0.981884  0.910922  0.589013  0.999536
4            0  0.982611  0.913082  0.601056  0.999556
5            0  0.982386  0.912358  0.598856  0.999650
```

Question:

1. Shouldn't approach #1 and #2 work for any amount of dataframes merged together?
2. Why did approach 1 and 2 created duplicates of '_id' and insert NaN values?

Comment: With your exact data, I cannot reproduce issue. No `NAN` rows show up with chain or loop merge. What is your environment? Python/pandas version? Also, does your data actually resemble posting.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6.1 and pandas 0.20.2 inside of conda environment. I retrieved all data from a mongoDB. I had to create my own datetime using python datetime for df1. I checked the type of date for all the other dfs (df2-4) and each has <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'> date type. So, I converted df1 datetime to <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>, but still approach 1 and 2 don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pd.concat with set_index

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('_id'), df2.set_index('_id'), df3.set_index('_id'), df4.set_index('_id')], axis = 1).reset_index()
```